# Mongoid: And - Or query

Tags: mongoid

I have this query:

```
User.or( { name: 'John' }, { name: 'Sara' } ).or( { age: 17 }, { age: 18 } ) )
```

It returns the next Criteria:

```
#<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"enabled"=>true, "$or"=>[{"name"=>"John"}, {"name"=>"Anoun"}, {"age"=>17}. {"age"=>18}]}
  options:  {}
  class:    User
  embedded: false>
```

But I want to do 'and' betweend two 'or' that return something like this:

```
#<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"enabled"=>true, "$and"=>[
    {"$or"=>[{"name"=>"John"}, {"name"=>"Anoun"}]}, 
    {"$or"=>[{"age"=>17}, {"age"=>18}]}
  ] }
  options:  {}
  class:    User
  embedded: false>
```

How would be the query ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

this might help you,

```
User.where(enabled: true)
    .and( 
          User.or( { name: 'John' }, { name: 'Sara' } ).selector,
          User.or( { age: 17 }, { age: 18 } ).selector
        )
```

this will return:

```
#<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"enabled"=>true, "$and"=>[{"$or"=>[{"name"=>"John"}, {"name"=>"Sara"}]}, {"$or"=>[{"age"=>17}, {"age"=>18}]}]}
  options:  {}
  class:    User
  embedded: false>
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't need chained $or queries here - you just want documents where the name is in a list, and where the age is in a list. Mongo provides this easily:

```
db.users.find({enabled: true, name: {$in: ["John", "Sara"]}, age: {$in: [17, 18]}})
```

In Mongoid parlance, this is simply:

```
User.where(enabled: true, name.in: ["John", "Sara"], age.in: [17, 18])
```